# Karate: How to fetch/store value of "nonce" from 'responseHeaders' into a variable to use in next request

Tags: karate

I need to fetch "nonce="MTU1NjU2NDgxMTAzNjo1MTYzOTU5NmRhZjlmYTU2NjZlZjcxM2MwNDE1MzUyNA=="" in responseheader

---

Comment: Below is response    
00:35:51.230 [main] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - response time in milliseconds: 749.89
1 < 401
1 < Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
1 < Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
1 < Date: Mon, 29 Apr 2019 19:05:51 GMT
1 < Expires: 0
1 < Pragma: no-cache
1 < Transfer-Encoding: chunked
1 < WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="ncs.com", qop="auth", nonce="MTU1NjU2NDgxMTAzNjo1MTYzOTU5NmRhZjlmYTU2NjZlZjcxM2MwNDE1MzUyNA=="
1 < X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
1 < X-Frame-Options: DENY
1 < X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below:

- def Authenticate = responseHeaders['WWW-Authenticate'][0]
- def myHeader = Authenticate.substring(Authenticate.lastIndexOf('", ')+2)

myHeader value would be  nonce="MTU1NjU2NDgxMTAzNjo1MTYzOTU5NmRhZjlmYTU2NjZlZjcxM2MwNDE1MzUyNA=="

Comment: Thanks Much Sud,  It perfectly worked.      Now I can use "myHeader" in next scenario request ,                                                                                                           * header Authorization = 'Digest username="+919898989898", realm="ncs.com", #(myHeader), uri="/backup/ra/appId", algorithm="MD5", qop=auth, nc=00000001, cnonce="Y8KjYCrw", response="68d72533df112d88b0462f97fd117f08"'

Comment: @PeterThomas, I have marked the answer as Accepted,    and How to use "myHeader " in other scenario

Comment: @Rajesh ask a new question please if you have more doubts

Comment: @PeterThomas sure   I will post a new question with detail test plan to achieve digest auth                     now Karate became hobby for me ☺